# array_column null, but 2d array given

Tags: php, arrays

Why is array_column warning me that it received a null in this snippet? It seems to get angry about what it receives inside of $hLA, but it's clearly a 2d array. The error I receive is: "PHP Warning:  array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given"

Values from a var_dump of $hLA:

```
$hL = pg_query("SELECT * FROM hubs");
$hLA = pg_fetch_all($hL);

function updateArticles($tP){
    global $hLA;
    $hmkey = array_search($tP['hm'], array_column($hLA, 'hm'));
}

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["hm"]=>string(12) "5CCF7F33B58C"
    ["hx"]=>string(1) "9"
    ["hy"]=>string(2) "14"
    ["zn"]=>string(6) "T1"
    ["r"]=>string(1) "n"
    ["a"]=>string(1) "n"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["hm"]=>string(12) "5CCF7FACBBFD"
    ["hx"]=>string(1) "1"
    ["hy"]=>string(1) "1"
    ["zn"]=>string(4) "R"
    ["r"]=>string(1) "y"
    ["a"]=>string(1) "n"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    ["hm"]=>string(12) "5CCF7FADCE84"
    ["hx"]=>string(1) "8"
    ["hy"]=>string(1) "5"
    ["zn"]=>string(4) "Exit"
    ["r"]=>string(1) "n"
    ["a"]=>string(1) "y"
  }
}
```

Comment: where `$hLA` is defined?

Comment: Outside the function, but is included with global $hLA;

Comment: The var_dump was done from inside the same function, so I know it's accessible.

Comment: The code works. You have a problem where you define `$hLA`. It clearly has a `null` value. You need to update the question with more code or we can't help you.

Comment: Can we get a smidgen more code to see the whole situation. Adding globals to the mix adds a level of debugging.

Comment: Sorry guys, I added some! My employer is really fussy about how much I'm allowed to share when asking on SO

Comment: I am just going to toss it out there is there a reason you use a global and not just pass a parameter?

Comment: Unless I'm blind the var_dump shows `array(4)`, but only has 3 values (`[0],[1],[2]`). Is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: yes jh1711, I removed one to be less 'verbose', forgot to take one out form the count! 

nerdlyist, that fixed it *massive facepalm*
But why does passing it instead of accessing the same variable through global fix the problem? Am I misunderstanding the purpose of global?

Comment: @T1960CT, when you address a specific user in the comments, you can put an @ sign in front of their username. That way they get a message in their inbox; just like you - as the owner of the question - get for all comments.

Comment: Thanks @jh1711 Haven't used SO very often. I appreciate your help.